# is my try catch block required?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have an aspect that intercepts a lot of methods in my code. I was wondering if joinPoint's signature and declaring type can ever be null. If no, then my try...catch is not required.

In other words, is try...catch block in following code required?

```
 private Object logPerfomanceInfo(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        StringBuilder tag = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            tag.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do not do anything, let the execution continue
        }
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(tag.toString());
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed(); // continue on the intercepted method
        stopWatch.stop();
        PerformanceUtils.logInPerf4jFormat(stopWatch.getStartTime(), stopWatch.getElapsedTime(), stopWatch.getTag(), stopWatch.getMessage(), getRemoteAddress());
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know whether it can be `null` but I think that if you *are* concerned about it being `null`, rather than catching every `Exception` you should check `if (signature != null) { ... }`.  your current code will swallow any apocalyptic error report, pretending it was just a `NullPointerException` thrown because there was no signature.

Comment: There are some cases that I've seen where this is necessary, but they are rare. At the very least, if you're going to eat the entire exception, especially in something like Spring, *log a warning.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if `joinPoint`'s signature and declaring type can ever be null.

No, they can't.

One way (long way) to verify is reading [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/AbstractAspectJAdvice.java#AbstractAspectJAdvice.currentJoinPoint%28%29) of Spring's implementation.

Alternatively, we can turn to the very good AspectJ documentation. The [javadoc for `JoinPoint#getSignature()`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getSignature%28%29) states

> Returns the signature at the join point.

And [`Signature#getDeclaringTypeName()`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/Signature.html#getDeclaringTypeName%28%29)

> Returns the fully-qualified name of the declaring type.

Both javadoc entries are very specific about what they return. It would make no sense for either of them to return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sotirios Delimanolis already said, every joinpoint has a (non-null) signature. But I have a few more hints for you concerning other parts of your code:

- If `logPerfomanceInfo(..)` is an advice, it must be `public`, not `private`. Otherwise it will not compile.
- You create a `StringBuilder` for each logging statement, but then call `append(..)` only once, using `+` for string concatenation. This makes the string builder pointless.
- Instead of manually concatenating declaring class and method name, you could just use one of the `Signature` methods `toString()`, `toShortString()` or `toLongString()`. That way you get a similar output and do not need to concatenate anything.
- If you time many methods, it might get expensive to create one of your `StopWatch` instances for each call. You do not need anything else than start and elapsed time anyway. The tag you put into the stop watch needs to be fetched later which is also overhead. Why not call the logging method directly? You don't want the aspect's advice to be more expensive than the timed method, do you? ;-)
- Where does the `message` come from in the `StopWatch`? Is it somehow synthesised automatically? Should it be set before it is used or is it empty otherwise?

Just for illustration, I mean something like this:

```java
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && !within(MyAspect) && !within(de.scrum_master.app.PerformanceUtils)")
public Object logPerfomanceInfo(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    PerformanceUtils.logInPerf4jFormat(
        startTime,
        System.nanoTime() - startTime,
        joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(),
        "My log message",
        getRemoteAddress()
    );
    return result;
}
```

**Update:** Alternatively, if you do want to use your fancy `StopWatch` class, you could add another `PerformanceUtils.logInPerf4jFormat(..)` method which directly consumes a `StopWatch` instead of urging the caller to extract stop watch internals by calling four methods one after another. This could and probably should be hidden in the logging method to make the calling code cleaner.

Comment: thanks for feedback. makes sense. i will make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No your code doesn't need Try/Catch or any throws clause.